# Application Installation Failed Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE FAILED MANIFEST MALFORMED

Tags: java, android

[I got this pop msg Error, i dont know what to do, i hope someone can help me, i allready tried to seek help everywhere i couldn't find any.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpOx7.png)

Here is the warning:
Application Installation Failed 
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE FAILED_MANIFEST MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmd11789010436.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #34): requires an android:value or android:resource attribute.

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing. 
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove.'e the application data! 
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

```
Here is my manifest.xmL. I don't know if i have anything wrong here, i tried
```

to search but i could not find the solution.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hfad.imdblogin">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.ActivityLoginPage" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.ActivitySignUp" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
         />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.ActivityHomepage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.CreateAccountActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.AnimeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.NotificationActivity"
                >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: why do you have two main launchers? Only 1 activity can be your main launcher activity

Comment: Remove Intent filters from your NotificationActivity if ActivityHompage is your main launching activity

Comment: I try to remove one of them and run the app again

Comment: I removed the intent filter under NotificationActivity, but the same error showed when i started the app again

Comment: Are you trying to use something from  `Facebook-sdk` without singing app on `Facebook developer account` and providing id?

Comment: Thanks Yupi1!!!!!!!!! it works now, it was about that Facebook-sdk, May god Bless u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `meta-data` contains FacebookApplicationId but no `Id` is provided here:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
```

And exception is pointing on that part that you didn't provide `Id` it should be:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="Your id here" />
```

Also check on official Facebook developer page about more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: I Fixed it just now, thanks alot for helping! Love ya!

Comment: Great, your welcome. Mark answer as correct if helped you resolve your issue.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: You have this sign ✓ near the answer you can then mark answer as correct.